# LINQ to XML with different files

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to write a generic utility which will parse XML and give me back a collection of customers.

The problem is, one of the files is missing one element.

I would like to know, if this kind of situation can be handled using LINQ or not.

While using normal XPATH or XMLDocument, we can ignore this or assign a default value in code.

Here is my code.

My XML files

Customer 1

```
<customers>
  <customer>
    <first_name>F1</first_name>
    <last_name>L1</last_name>
  </customer>
  <customer>
    <first_name>F2</first_name>
    <last_name>L2</last_name>
  </customer>
</customers>
```

Customer 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<customers>
  <customer>
    <first_name>F1</first_name>
    <middle_name>M1</middle_name>
    <last_name>L1</last_name>
  </customer>
  <customer>
    <first_name>F2</first_name>
    <middle_name>M2</middle_name>
    <last_name>L2</last_name>
  </customer>
</customers>
```

My class

```
public class Customer
      {
         public string FirstName { get; set; }
         public string MiddleName { get; set; }
         public string LastName { get; set; }
      }
```

My code for parsing these XML files

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\\Projects\\Customer1.xml");

        var cCusts = from c in doc.Descendants("customer")
                     select new Customer
                     {
                         FirstName = c.Element("first_name").Value,
                         MiddleName = c.Element("middle_name").Value,
                         LastName = c.Element("last_name").Value,
                     };
```

Now, when I execute my code I get "object reference not set" error, and I know it is because; it is failing to find the  element.

But with the same query can we actually check the "null" if element is not present or do I need to write different code for customer 1 and 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [cast `XElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.op_explicit(v=vs.110).aspx) to string instead of getting the value from `Value` property. This way you'll get `null` instead of null reference exception when `middle_name` is not exist :

```
var cCusts = from c in doc.Descendants("customer")
                     select new Customer
                     {
                         FirstName = (string)c.Element("first_name"),
                         MiddleName = (string)c.Element("middle_name"),
                         LastName = (string)c.Element("last_name")
                     };
```

Comment: Just one thing.. Can I use c.Element("middle_name")+"" instead of (string) just to make sure code doesn't throw error if it fails to cast??

Comment: I checked this fiddle. If you change it to the way I have mentioned, in output, it writes whole tag <middle_name>M1<middle_name> instead of value.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like

```
 LastName = c.Element("last_name")?.Value;
```

or

```
LastName = c.Element("last_name")?.Value ?? "N/A";
```

The `?.` operator will check if `c.Element("last_name")` is null and return null if so (meaning you won't get an exception). If you want to add some default value, you can go with the second option in which `??` checks if the previous expression is `null` and gives `LastName` a default "N/A" value.

Also, you have and extra `,` at the end of `LastName = c.Element("last_name").Value,`.

Comment: This will only work if this is a single statement. In the LINQ query which I have pasted above; if I change this, the code does not compile.

Comment: It complies just fine for me. What error are you getting?

Comment: Error 17 Invalid expression term '.' 
Error 18 Syntax error, ':' expected

Comment: If I paste it as is in above query...Could you please paste the whole query to get Customer object?

Comment: Here it is : https://gist.github.com/Rastamas/af5d09ca37297034aa9120d34441883f
 
What visual studio / compiler version are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2013... Is it because of that? Not working here either https://dotnetfiddle.net/9OLnvc the link provided by @har07

Comment: Yeah it's because of that. The ?. operator was introduced in C# 6, which came with Visual Studio 2015 and .NET 4.6 (this is why it doesn't work in the fiddle either). har07's answer works perfectly without having to worry about all that, so I say stick to that for now :)